# Not able to connect to a Openstack Instance from external machine

Tags: networking, openstack

The IP of of an instance created through Openstack is 10.0.0.2. But when I tried to ping this IP from other machine, it was not successful, however I am able to ping this IP from the machine on which Openstack(Devstack) is installed.
What could be the reason and how to resolved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you: http://www.liquidstate.net/blog/technology/openstack-havana-home-lab-on-centos6-with-external-networking/

Basically, you need a virtual router to connect from you LAN to OpenStack private network.

I think, you don't need a Floating IP exactly on each instance. Only a virtual router, then you can create a static route on each machine in you LAN, for example:

## ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.1.100 dev em1

Good Luck!

Comment: This link (http://www.liquidstate.net/blog/technology/openstack-havana-home-lab-on-centos6-with-external-networking/) describes about CentOS settings. Did you have corresponding ubuntu specific configuration settings?

Comment: It worked for me just by adding the static ip route from the external machine to the Openstack instance. Thanks, it was a useful answer @diablinux

Answer (score 0):

This IP is a private one, by default, when you deploy a new instance it is deployed with a private IP.

If you want to have a public IP, you need to create a floating IP for your project and afterward, you should assign one IP from this pool to the server instance that you have created previously.

After that you could access to your server instance without any problem.

I hope that it could help you.